# Help solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

my Calculus II class is nearing the end of the quarter and we've just started differential equations to get ready for Calculus III. In my homework, I came upon these problems.

One of the problems was:

Find the general solution to the differential equation 
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = t^3 + 2t^2 - 8t.$$

The teacher just said to integrate. So I did. Then in question 8a it gives the differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = y^3 + 2y^2 - 8y.$$

and asks "Why can't we find a solution like we did to the previous problem? My guess was: "In 7 we were integrating with respect to t. Since this equation is the highest order derivative, we can't solve it like # 7". Although, I have no confidence in that answer and I'm not sure it makes total sense even to me.

Also, part 8B. asks: Show that the constant function $y(t) = 0$ is a solution.

I've done a problem like this before, except that it wasn't a constant function. This problem seems like a question that asks: "show that every member of the family of functions $y = (\ln x + C)/x$ is a solution to the differential equation (some diff. equation)" except it seems a little bit different.

Any hints on how I can solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parts of problems that say "show that [explicitly given function] is a solution" can be solved by simply "plugging in".  E.g., if you're supposed to show that $y(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$ is a solution to the differential equation $dy/dt=y^2$, then you should compute $dy/dt=\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$, compute $y^2=\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$, and "plug them in" to check that the differential equation is satisfied for this choice of $y$.

You're correct that the difference in the second problem is that you no longer have the derivative with respect to $t$ expressed as a function of $t$.  When the equation involves both a function $y$ and its derivative (or derivatives), it can generally be more difficult to solve.  In this case, a hint I'll give you is that $dy/dt=1/(dt/dy)$ (e.g., see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_rule_for_inverses)). You can first turn things around and think of $t$ as a function of $y$.  You can find $t(y)$ using similar methods to the first problem (but with a more complicated function), and then find the inverse function to get $y(t)$.

A somewhat more general method of solving differential equations that applies in this case is [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the main variable is $y$ and you separate the variables to integrate and obtain the solution

**Hint 1:**

The first equation is very easy, so :

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=t^3 + 2t^2 - 8t \Rightarrow dy = (t^3 + 2t^2 - 8t) dt \Rightarrow $$

$$  \int dy = \int (t^3 + 2t^2 - 8t) dt $$   ( which is the left side ? )

**Hint2:**

For the other.
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y^3 + 2y^2 - 8y \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{y^3 + 2y^2 - 8y}dy =  dt $$

Then proceed integrating.

Answer (score 1):

In the first question, you are given the derivative in terms of the variable. But in the second question, you are given an expression for the derivative that involves *the function*. For instance, it would be one thing if you were told $\frac{dy}{dx} = x$ (which would mean that $y = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C$), and a completely different thing if you are told $\frac{dy}{dx}=y$ (this tells you that the function $y$ is equal to its derivative; which means that $y=Ae^x$ for some constant $A$).

Actually, we *can* solve the second differential equation; but we don't solve it by simple integration, just like we don't solve the equation $y' = y$ by integrating.

Showing that $y(t)=0$ is a solution to the second equation is just a question of plugging in $0$ for $y$ and verifying that you get a solution by verifying that the resulting equality is true.

You never said what question 8a was, through; were you asked to *solve* the differential equation, or just to say what is the difference between it and the previous one?